# How to restrict "Members" to add devices through Xcode?

Tags: ios, app-store

From Xcode 7 onwards. Developers can create wildcard provisioning profiles and app ids from Xcode.

However, For **Apple Developer Program** or **Apple Developer Enterprise Program**

The members of the team can register any device from Xcode due to Automatic Signing. Although they cannot register the devices through their developer account.
As mentioned on the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

It specifically says: *Xcode automatically registers devices when needed, as described in Launching Your App on Devices*

So, now the question arises: Is there a way to stop the members to be able to automatically add devices through Xcode?

An Agent or Admin would want to have this control and prevent any of its members to add devices by themselves through Xcode.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you asked Apple yet?

Comment: Yes, I already filed a bug on the portal.
https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=33098657

Comment: Did you get any answer yet?

Comment: No, there's no response yet.